# handle Exception in Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

Hello Friends Iam trying to handle

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFoundException
```

this exception but iam failed to do so.
In this way i handle SnapshotNotFoundException.

```
<transition on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFoundException"
        to="exceptionHandler" />
```

Answer (score 4):

That declarative Exception handling does not seem to work for internal Web Flow exceptions. For this particular case, we had to implement a custom [`FlowHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/webflow/mvc/servlet/FlowHandler.html).[`handleException()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/webflow/mvc/servlet/FlowHandler.html#handleException%28org.springframework.webflow.core.FlowException,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29).

Something like:

```
public class CustomFlowHandler extends AbstractFlowHandler
{
    @Override
    public String handleException(FlowException e, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        if (e instanceof FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException)
        {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof SnapshotNotFoundException)
            {
                // TODO return the desired location string. See javadoc for options
                return "serverRelative:/missingSnapshot.html";
            }
        }
        return super.handleException(e, request, response);
    }
}
```

And in Spring configuration file:

```
<!-- custom flow handler -->
<bean name="your-flow-name" class="yourpackage.CustomFlowHandler"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @dbreaux. but Iam quite rookie in SFW. It will be a great help if you explain a little more or with code snippet or how to implement this