# How to handle FlowException in spring webflow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflow

Objective is to redirect if i come across flow exception
Im using following for handling rest of the exception

```
<global-transitions>
<transition on-exception="java.lang.Exception" to="invalid"/>
</global-transitions>
```

Im getting following error in case of invalid url input

```
due to exception [Badly formatted flow execution key 'e1s1FFFF', the expected format is 'e<executionId>s<snapshotId>']
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.BadlyFormattedFlowExecutionKeyException: Badly formatted flow execution key 'e1s1FFFF', the expected format is 'e<executionId>s<snapshotId>'
at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.AbstractFlowExecutionRepository.parseSnapshotId(AbstractFlowExecutionRepository.java:221)
at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.AbstractFlowExecutionRepository.parseFlowExecutionKey(AbstractFlowExecutionRepository.java:120)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:254)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
```

How to handle this exception and redirect to designated template

input for this is invalid as following

```
localhost:8080/test?execution=e156
```

while actual input would be

```
localhost:8080/test?execution=e1s1
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24123213/796761. (In short, that declarative exception handling doesn't seem to work for internal WebFlow exceptions)

Comment: hi @dbreaux i tried implementing by adding flowlocation and extra xml for configuring bean and adding same but did'nt resolve can you provide some more info to resolve this issue.

Comment: following is the sepearte question link for same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74301528/spring-web-flow-how-to-handle-flow-exception-org-springframework-webflow-execu